# MongoCollection to JSON array

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

After going through tons of [examples](https://www.javatips.net/api/org.bson.json.jsonwriter), I couldn't find relevant code, Basically I want to serialize the JSON array over the wire to the client.

```
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = ((MongoCollection)data).find().iterator();
try {
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        response.getWriter().write(cursor.next().toJson());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
break;
```

---

**Attempt** Doesn't work but is something close to what I'm looking for.

```
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = ((MongoCollection)data).find().iterator();
JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonWriter(response.getWriter());
jsonWriter.writeStartDocument();
jsonWriter.writeStartArray();

while(cursor.hasNext()) {
    jsonWriter.writeStartDocument();
    jsonWriter.writeString(cursor.next().toJson());
    jsonWriter.writeEndDocument();
}

jsonWriter.writeEndArray();
jsonWriter.writeEndDocument();

cursor.close();
```

Any serialization solutions for mongodb collections?

**Naive way** works

```
try {
    response.getWriter().write("[");
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        response.getWriter().write(cursor.next().toJson() + (cursor.hasNext() ? "," : ""));
    }
    response.getWriter().write("]");
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper for this purpose.

Comment: I'm trying to find oracle json library solution

Answer (score 0):

I assume your desired output value is not an "infinite json", otherwise put in place some kind of pagination.

Basically with java mongo driver you have a org.bson.Document class, and with method toJson you create a string with inside Json for your Document, reference: https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.2/org/bson/Document.html#toJson--

**Note**: basic encoder take care of handling arrays for you